# Python longitudinal data, filling NaN values

Tags: python, time-series, nan

I have a dataset on health indicators, with columns such as 'Country', 'Year', 'GDP', and 'Life expectancy'. The data covers the years 2000-2015.

So, there is data for many health indicators for each country for each of the years from 2000-2015.

Many of the variables have missing (NaN) data for specific years/countries.

1. So, for instance, How would I replace NaN values with average/mean values specific to the given country/year range for all countries?
2. Additionally, since this is longitudinal data, it would be great to maintain the general trend over time within each country's 16 years of data. Is there a way to replace NaN data for each country, accounting for the general trend for that country/variable over time?

If you guys could explain both methods, that would be phenomenal.

link to data: https://www.kaggle.com/kumarajarshi/life-expectancy-who

Thanks,
D

[screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqWmE.png)

Comment: example data and exaple output would help.

Comment: @U12-Forward, I'm not sure where to start after loading the data as a DataFrame, so my current output wouldn't be very helpful for y'all.

Comment: Just copy the dataframe and post it here, also show your desired output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into the [pd.Dataframe.interpolate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) method. It has different methods for filling NaNs in a time series or filling in missing values.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.